# In jagged array how to use columns as array values from different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

how to use jagged array for copy and pasting specific columns(like B,J,N,M,U,V,) from 12 xl sheets and finally it has to stored in a seperate single sheet.

For Example:
In Sheet1 I need B,J,N,M has to be copied 
In Sheet2 I need B,J,N,O,U,V,X,AO to be copied
.
.
.
Upto Sheet12 I need like this specific columns and its values till its last row has to be copied and finally 12 sheet values has to be pasted at the end of the new worksheet.Pls someone help me using vba

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and amend your question accordingly. You will receive little to no help as your question is currently written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna try. Is it something like this? Alter the code to your need of course and set more arrays for the column indexes if you need. This will paste all of these columns on a new sheet.

```
Sub test()
Dim a() As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim newWS As Worksheet
Dim nextColumn As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long, o As Long
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set newWS = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
a = Array(1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11) 'column indexes

With wb
    nextColumn = 1
    For i = 1 To 12
        With .Worksheets(i)
            For o = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
                lastrow = .Cells(65536, a(o)).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range(.Cells(1, a(o)), .Cells(lastrow, a(o))).Copy
                newWS.Cells(1, nextColumn).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                nextColumn = nextColumn + 1
            Next o
        End With
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Bernd, It is a really helpful code but my problem retains, upto sheet8 I had a specific columns has to be copied. Finally those columns has to be come in last sheet with same column headers.My array(column index for those 8 sheets will look this)=>My_req_col_arr(From sht1-B,J,N,R,V,Z,AD,AH,AL,AP).( sht2-B,J,M,Q,U,Y,AC). (sht3-B,J,M,Q,U,Y,AD,AI).(sht4-B,J,M,Q,U,YAC,AG,AK). (sht5-B,J,N,R,V,Z,AD,AH).(sht6-B,J,M,Q,U,Y,AC,AG,AK,AQ,AS,AW).(sht7- B,J,M,Q,U,Y,AC,AG,AK,AO,AS,AW). (sht8-B,J,M,Q,U,Y,AC,AG,AL)

Comment: Hi Magesh, that is actually possible with a little tweaking: the above code is made as if you would need the same columns in each sheet, now that is not what you need, I see. We just need to make a  2 Dimensional array for the column numbers (I'm using numbers instead of letters.
for that 2 dimensional array it would be best you'd use a sheet to store, then you can read this table as an array (a = range()) and if you use a line per worksheet we can pull it with 
.Range(.Cells(1, a(i, o)), .Cells(lastrow, a(i, o))).Copy
I hope that is somehow clear (also lastrow has to be amended in that way